# Reference for stochastic dominance

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, soft-question

Is there a good book reference for stochastic dominance properties of random processes on $\mathbb{N}$?
For example characterizations of the following property for a stochastic process X(n) on $\mathbb{N}$ with $X(n)\le n$: There exists a non-negative integer-valued random variable X that stochastically dominates all $X(n)$ for all $n\ge 0$, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(X\ge x) \ge \mathbb{P}(X(n)\ge x)$.
Thank you :)